# jQuery: Sort tiles to two columns. Default order stored in localStorage

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, local-storage, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to place items in two different columns with the flexibility to drag and drop from one column to another. Save the order in the localStorage to maintain the layout on page-load.

This is what I have so far:

(With a huge thanks) This is the base of my code:
http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/collpasible-drag-drop-panels/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Drag Drop Panels - Web Developer Plus Demos</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("order"));
        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            var columnId = data[i]["columnId"];
            var itemorder = data[i]["itemorder"];
            var orderArray = itemorder.toString().split(',');
            var listArray = $('.column .dragbox');
            for (var i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
                $('.column').append(listArray[orderArray[i]-1]);
            }
        });
    });

    $('.dragbox').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).find('h2').addClass('collapse');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('h2').removeClass('collapse');
        })
        .find('h2').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        })
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
        })
        .end()
        .find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $('.column').sortable({
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: 'h2',
        cursor: 'move',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.4,
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $(ui.item).find('h2').click();
            var sortorder='';
            var dataSave = [];
            $('.column').each(function(){
                var columnId=$(this).attr('id');
                var itemorder=$(this).sortable('toArray');

                item = {
                    'columnId':columnId,
                    'itemorder':itemorder,
                };
                dataSave.push(item);
                localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify(dataSave));
            });
        }
    })
    .disableSelection();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Drag n Drop Panels</h3>
<div class="column" id="column1">
    <div class="dragbox" id="1" >
        <h2>Handle 1</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" > This is a panel. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="2" >
        <h2>Handle 2</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" > This is a panel. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="3" >
        <h2>Handle 3</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" > This is a panel. </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column2" >
    <div class="dragbox" id="4" >
        <h2>Handle 4</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" > This is a panel. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="5" >
        <h2>Handle 5</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" > This is a panel. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="6" >
        <h2>Handle 6</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" > This is a panel. </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into jQuery UI Sortable Portlets: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

This way you have default areas for your panels to drop into.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: ".portlet-header",
    cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
    placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
  });

  $(".portlet")
    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
    .find(".portlet-header")
    .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

  $(".portlet-toggle").on("click", function() {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 520px;
}

.column {
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.portlet {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.portlet-header {
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.portlet-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.portlet-content {
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.portlet-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Images</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I can certainly use some of the suggested code to improve my panels.